# RestSharp - Passing Token into GET call

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I'm using OAuth2.0 to obtain a token which must be passed alongside the GET call.

I've built the POST method to obtain a token.

How can I use this token in a GET method to pass it alongside the call that I'm making?

Would the following work or is there another attribute that I should be using?

```
request.Method = "GET";
request.AddParameter= ("token", TokenVariableStoringValueFromPOST);
```

Comment: Are you sure you dont want to pass it as a Header value?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the OAuth2.0 services accepts the token in the header such as: "Authorization: Bearer #{your_token}".

You can easily achieve like this:

```
request.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " & TokenVariableStoringValueFromPOST, ParameterType.HttpHeader)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your token in the request authorization header

```
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <your AuthToken>")
```